# Non root user in aws fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, security, containers, aws-fargate

Given that we do not run containers on our hosts, is it required to run your containers as a non-root user in Fargate as is recommended in normal scenario?

Thanks & Regards
Sunil